# pear/MDB2_Driver_oci8 requires PHP extension "oci8"

Tags: php, oracle, sles, pecl, pear

I got this Error:

```
unable to find package 'MDB2_Driver_oci8' file 'MDB2/Driver/oci8.php'
```

so I tried to install it with

```
pear install MDB2_Driver_oci8-1.4.1
```

but following Error is showing up

```
pear/MDB2_Driver_oci8 requires PHP extension "oci8"
No valid packages found
install failed
```

**BUT** I have installed oci8. In php.ini the *extension_dir* is pointing to the right directory, where the file oci8.so is. In my *phpinfo.php* i get following output:

[image]

It seems that the extension is successfully installed. Am I missing something in the a*pache2.conf* or in the *php.ini* ?

> OS: SUSE Enterprise Linux 12
>
> Apache2.4.16
>
> PHP 5.5.14

Answer (score 0):

**What i forgot to do:**

There are two *php.ini* files. One in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` . I forget to configure the *cli* file and I didn't add the extension *oci8.so*.

I think everyone who has more to do with PHP knows this, I only provide the solution because maybe they are some newbie like my searching for the solution.